# Creating Progress Bar from an html table value

Tags: html, css, html-table, progress

I need help on this.
I'm trying to create a simple progress bar based on a value from another TD element.
Here's my code below. 
I want the width property value of `<hr>` equal to the value set on the first `<TD>` element.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <TD id="item">70%</td>
    <td width=200 style="border: 2px solid silver;padding:none">
      <hr style="color:#c00;background-color:#c00;height:15px; border:none;
                 margin:0;" align="left" width=50%;        />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
widthValue = document.getElementById("item").innerText;
document.getElementsByTagName("hr")[0].style.width = widthValue;
```

which will get the text contents of the `<td>`, and set it to the width of the `<hr>` element. You'd probably be better off giving the `<hr>` an id, so you can set its with by id rather than relying on finding it by tag name.

Comment: Thanks! It looks great using jsfiddle. This is what I'm looking for. But one last thing, should i add it inside the '<header>' tag? and how? sorry for the noob question, i'm still trying to understand jscript.

Comment: You can put it in a `<script>` tag in the header, and inside of an onload function....`window.onload = function() {  //put the javascript here! }`

Comment: here's the jsfiddle link of what I'm trying to do: [jsfiddle]:http://jsfiddle.net/XhxkX/ 

Also..
CAn you help me modify the page in such a way that:  
1. original bar color is blue  
2. if it reaches beyond 80% bar color turns red.

Comment: **Update:** i was able to solve the first instead of using getelementbyid, i'm using getElementsByClass. my problem left is how to change the bar colors if it reaches a certain value.

@adrien-delessert, thanks for the assist.

Comment: I fooled around with the fiddle you posted above and added two lines to make the bar turn from blue to red if the value is over 80%, it's pretty straightforward: http://jsfiddle.net/XhxkX/5/    Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Hi sorry it seems like the window.onload function doesn't work on my page. here's my code:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../Backup/2012/Web Projects/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
var widthValue = document.getElementsByClassName("item")[0].innerText;
$(document).getElementsByTagName("hr")[0].style.width = widthValue;​
};
</script>`

Comment: Thanks a lot @adrien  that's exactly what i wanted.... my last problem now is i can't make it work on the actual page using the code above.